# Logical way to prove this probability

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, logic

So let us say we toss a coin 'n' times and the probability that the number of times head shows up is odd = p.

Let us take a case where 'n' is odd.

We know for 1 toss, probability of head appearing = probability of tail appearing (and they are mutually exclusive/exhaustive). So we can say probability that the number of times head shows up is odd = number of times tails shows up is odd = p ------- (1)
(just making the transformation heads $\leftrightarrow$ tails).

In a single set of 'n' throws, in every case where heads appears odd number of times, tails has to appear even number of times (like n = 5, heads appears once, tails appears 4 times, heads appears thrice, tails appears twice and heads appears 5 times, tails does not appear). So the probability that the number of times tails appears is even = probability that the number of times heads appears is odd = p ------- (2)

Using (1) and (2) to get : probability that the number of times tails shows up is odd = probability that the number of times tails shows up is even = p. We obviously have only these two cases which are both mutually exclusive and exhaustive.

$\therefore p+p = 1 \implies p = \frac{1}{2}$

My question is, is there any way we can prove this for 'n' even in a similiar logical manner?

We cannot do exactly this as by the first step we get : probability that number of times tails appears odd number of times = probability that number of times heads appears odd number of times = p (probability of head = tail on one throw)

By the second step we get : heads appears odd number of times, since 'n' is even now, tails appears odd numbers of times (and probability of tails appearing odd number of times is already known to be p) which is unfortunately of no use (but we know the answer is still $p = \frac{1}{2}$).

P.S. : Sorry this question appears much more typing/confusing than mathematically straightforward but I have a problem in the logical way of dealing with this proabability and I did not find any post on this site dealing with this specific problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prerequisite**

You have proved that $P(\text{even heads})=P(\text{odd heads})=\frac{1}{2}$ when tossing a coin an odd number of times.

**Even Number of Tosses**

Why don't we divide the tossing session into two: toss $m_{1}$ times, then toss $m_{2}$ times, where $m_{1},m_{2}$ are odd integers and $m_{1}+m_{2}=n$.

To get an odd number of heads, you need to get an even number of heads in the first session and an odd number of heads in the second or vice versa. Therefore, we have:

$$
P(\text{odd heads})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: Wow, thank you for this ingenious solution. This is exactly what I was looking for, minimal mathematics and more logical analysis. I just have 1 small doubt, wouldn't P(odd heads) = $\frac{m_1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{m_2}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{m_1 + m_2}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ (using $m_1 + m_2 = n$)?

Comment: $P_{m_{1}}(\text{odd})P_{m_{2}}(\text{even})+P_{m_{1}}(\text{even})P_{m_{2}}(\text{odd})$, where all of these $P$s are $0.5$ for odd $m$s right?

Comment: Oh ok those were the cases you broke it up in, I was talking about something different. Thank you again for this solution

Comment: @HamLemon In case you are interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4841534/751970 . For your problem, $x_{1}=0.5$ so $x_{m}=0.5$ for all $m$

Comment: Ok, I'll be sure to check it out. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For the odd case, a simple symmetry argument works:  exactly one of $H,T$ was tossed an odd number of times and it is equally likely to have been either.

For the even case, we know that either both $H,T$ are tossed an even number of times, or both were tossed an odd number of times.

For $n=2$, say, the only ways in which $H$ is tossed an odd number of times are $HT,TH$ giving us a probability of $\frac 12$.  Thus we know the claim is true for $n≤3$ at least.

We proceed inductively.  Suppose we know that for $n≤N$ the probability is $\frac 12$.  Now consider $N+1$ tosses and look at the results of the first toss.  Either the first coin is  $H$ and then we need an even number of $H's$ thereafter (prob $\frac 12$ by the induction hypothesis) or the first toss is $T$ and then we need an odd number of $H's$ thereafter (again prob. $\frac 12$).  Thus the probability of seeing an odd number of $H's$ in $N+1$ tosses is $$\frac 12\times \frac 12+\frac12\times \frac 12=\frac 12$$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it does provide a more logical solution than mathematical methods. But still, my doubt is if there is a way to not use induction or mathematics of combinatorics to prove the answer is ½. Rather as in my original answer I have stated the method for 'n' odd, where only the last step involves mathematics (and that too basic addition) is there a way to go like that for 'n' even where you apply minimal mathematics/induction and logically process that probability of getting even number of tails = probability of getting odd number of tails (so that we get p = ½)?

Answer (score 1):

$2k-1$ will always be an odd number

$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac {n}{2}\rfloor} {2k-1\choose n}$

Will count the number of ways of flipping an odd number of heads.

$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac {n}{2}\rfloor} {2k-1\choose n}\frac {1}{2^n}$ will be the probability that you will see an odd number of head.

And what remains is to prove that

$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac {n}{2}\rfloor} {2k-1\choose n}\frac {1}{2^n} = \frac {1}{2}$

One of the properties of the binomial coefficients:
${2k-1\choose n} = {2k-2\choose n-1}+{2k-1\choose n-1}$

Substituting into our formula above for the count, and re-indexing:

$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac {n}{2}\rfloor} {2k-1\choose n}\\
 \sum_\limits{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac {n}{2}\rfloor} {2k-2\choose n-1}+{2k-1\choose n-1}\\
 \sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1} {k\choose n-1}$

Which sums to $2^{n-1}$

In our probability formula.
$\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1} {k\choose n-1} = \frac {2^{n-1}}{2^n} = \frac 12$

Alternatively, we can prove this by induction.

Base case: if we flip the coin one time there is a $\frac 12$ probability we flip and odd number of heads.

Suppose, if we flip a coin $n$ times, we have a $\frac 12$ probability to see an odd number of heads.

What is the probability of seeing an odd number of heads on $n+1$ flips?

Either we have an odd number of heads on the first n flips followed by a tails. Or, we have an even number of heads on the first n flips followed by a heads.

$\frac 12\cdot \frac 12 + (1-\frac 12)\frac 12 = \frac 12$

Comment: Thank you for these 2 methods, they are actually new to me, and they are quite nice. But in my original question, my challenge was to prove this logically in a similiar way as we did for 'n' odd. Mathematically I am sure everybody has some method to prove it, but logically while applying minimal maths/induction was the problem which I was trying to find a solution for