# Closed Form of A Sequence with Recursive Relation

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

**Problem Statement**

This problem is inspired by another problem I worked on recently. Consider a sequence of positive numbers $x_{m}$ defined by its first value $0<x_{1}<1$ and the following recursive relation for $p,q\geq 1$:

$$
x_{p+q}=x_{p}+x_{q}-2x_{p}x_{q}
$$

The problem then asks for a closed form of $x_{m}$.

**My Solution**

The recursive relation can be rewritten as the following:

$$
x_{p+q}=x_{p}\cdot\left(1-x_{q}\right)+\left(1-x_{p}\right)\cdot x_{q}
$$

From this relation, it's quite trivial to see that $0<x_{m}<1$ for all $m\geq 1$. Looking at the inequality, the first thing that came to my mind was to treat $x_{m}$ as a probability:

Consider a (potentially unfair) coin with probability $x_{1}$ to land head. One can think of $x_{m}$ as the probability that there are an odd number of heads when the coin is tossed $m$ times. This fit the recursive relation, because to have an odd number of heads in $p+q$ tosses, either we have an odd number of heads in the first $p$ tosses & an even number of heads in the remaining $q$ tosses, or the other way around. Thus, a closed form expression is possible:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x_{m}&=\sum_{\text{odd }j}\binom{m}{j}\cdot x_{1}^{j}\left(1-x_{1}\right)^{m-j}
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[1-\left(1-2x_{1}\right)^{m}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

**Remarks**

This is a solution using probability / combinatorial argument. I am wondering if there are other alternatives e.g. pure algebraic solutions or something else.

Comment: OEIS has several triangles apparently consisting of coefficients of powers of $x_1$ in $x_m$ (with different signs though), e.g. https://oeis.org/A115068.

Comment: You could write a recursion with $x_{p+1}=x_p(1-2x_1)+x_1$ and get the same solution of $x_p= \frac12-\frac12(1-2x_1)^p$ as you and @RobertIsrael found different ways

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really a recursion, it's a functional equation.
Write the equation as
$$ 1 - 2 x_{p+q} = (1 - 2 x_p) (1 - 2 x_q) $$
Thus if $y = 1 - 2 x$ we have
$y_{p+q} = y_p y_q$, which is easy to solve: $y_p = c^p$, i.e.
$x_p = (1-c^p)/2$, for arbitrary $c$.

Comment: That's cool, I have very little experience with functional equation. I may need to look more into that field